# Is there any way to verify sectors on a hard drive to a disk on linux?

Tags: linux, hard-drive

I just tripped and fell and my computer happened to break my fall, smashing onto the stairs. I am slightly worried that there might be some damage to the hard drive on my computer. It is still running, and shows no visible damage, but the boot disk is an SSD and it has a secondary HDD in it, neither of which shows any damage, software or hardware. I am still concerned that some of the sectors might be damaged, although the disk mounts fine. Is there any utility on Linux to check for bad or damaged sectors on a hard drive? Thanks.

Comment: Before testing, you should back up your data. Testing puts drives under a lot of stress. They might well fail right then and there.

Comment: Also, listen for inusual sounds from the drive.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to run "badblocks -v /dev/sdX" which will take a very long time, but will thoroughly test your disk for bad errors.

Using smartctl will tell you only about errors which are known to the hard drive controller (ie read attempts which have failed).  It can be used to confirm what the drive thinks of its health, but not what its health actually is if its been damaged recently.

I'd not run badblocks on the SSD, as the SSD is immune to drops as its solid state, and running badblocks will (slightly) shorten the lifespan of the disk for no advantage.

Answer (score 0):

There are many utilities which checks bad sectors in Linux. One of them is smartctl.

```
sudo smartctl -H /dev/sda1
```

For more information, refer article.

http://www.tecmint.com/check-linux-hard-disk-bad-sectors-bad-blocks/

Comment: `smartctl` doesn’t really check for bad sectors. It just retrieves the disks self-diagnostic info as-is. You can trigger tests, too, but not with `-H`. ;)